# Why is sizeof() of this array illegal?

Tags: c++, arrays, sizeof

I have the following array:

```
static std::pair<const Type, const size_t> typemap_[];
```

defined as

```
std::pair<const talos::Message::Type, const size_t> talos::Message::typemap_[8] = {
{ talos::Message::Type::Empty, typeid(int).hash_code() },
{ talos::Message::Type::Keyboard , typeid(int).hash_code() },
...
```

Why does this

```
sizeof(typemap_);
```

give a compile time error

> Error C2070 'std::pair []':
>   illegal sizeof operand

even though this

```
sizeof(typemap_[0]);
```

is legal and the array is of a fixed size?

Type is a defined as:

```
enum class Type {...}
```

Comment: Each `c++` source file is compiled independent of the other files in the project. If the file that produces the error does not have access to the definition of `typemap_` (through the files it includes, directly or indirectly) but only to its declaration then it cannot know its size. Put the size of the array into its declaration and it will work.

Comment: `sizeof(typemap_[0])` doesn't care about `typemap_[]` as an array. It is the size of its first element and that one is computable (if the definition of `Type` is known) because it is `sizeof(std::pair<const Type, const size_t>)`.

Comment: @axiac Ah ok thanks! That explains it. The definition is in a .cpp file and the sizeof(typemap_) in the header file.

Comment: Each `.cpp` file in the project is compiled separately. It knows only the information it gets through the `#include` directives.

Comment: Replace the `static` declaration in the declaration of your array with `external`. A `static` variable is not available in other files. If you put `static` in the declaration in a header file, each `.cpp` file that includes the header file will have its own instance of that variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems the compiler is missing the definition of the `typemap_` variable. Since it's static you probably have it hidden in one of the source files.

If you put everything you have now into the same source the solution will work. For example:

```
enum class Type {None, Some} ;
static std::pair<const Type, const size_t> typemap_[] = {
    { Type::None, typeid(int).hash_code() },
    { Type::Some , typeid(int).hash_code() },
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "sizeof: " << sizeof(typemap_) << " " << sizeof(typemap_[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Works well and outputs `sizeof: 32 16`.

Same time `sizeof` of a single element is legal since the compiler knows what the array consists of even without knowing its actual size.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no *definition* of `static std::pair<const Type, const size_t> typemap_[];` in the current translation unit but only this *declaration*, then the compiler cannot possibly know its size, since there is no size in the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

An array of unknown bound is an *incompletely-defined object type*; its size and layout is unknown. The declaration of `typemap_` only declares an array of unknown bound, without the definition we can't get its size so `sizeof(typemap_);` fails.

[[basic.types]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#5),

> an array of unknown bound or of incomplete element type, is an *incompletely-defined object type*. <sup>[42](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#footnote-42)</sup>
>
> <sup>42)</sup> The size and layout of an instance of an incompletely-defined object type is unknown.

[[basic.types]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#6),

> The declared type of an array object might be an array of unknown bound and therefore be incomplete at one point in a translation unit and complete later on; the array types at those two points (“array of unknown bound of T” and “array of N T”) are different types.

Answer (score 0):

Start by creating a reproducible example:

```
static char c[];

char c[8] = "";

int main()
{
    return sizeof c;
}
```

Well, that won't even compile, as we can't declare `c` static and incomplete:

```
49668931.cpp:1:13: error: storage size of ‘c’ isn’t known
 static char c[];
             ^
```

Change that to `extern` and it's fine:

```
extern char c[];

char c[8] = "";

int main()
{
    return sizeof c;
}
```

However, if we need the size of `c` before it's complete, then of course it fails:

```
extern char c[];

int main()
{
    return sizeof c;
}

char c[8] = "";
```

```
49668931.cpp:5:19: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘char []’
     return sizeof c;
                   ^
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put the number o elments of the static array in the declaration. If later on I change the number in the implementation file, compiler will notify via some type mismatch diagnostic.

It is also possible to return the size in a static function, but the definition must reside in the same module as the array initialization; therefore the function might be inlined but never constexpr.